# How can i use returning id in multiple requests (postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

For my task i need to add a main entry and then add some additional, using the id of the added record.
Now i use request with "returning id":

```
with rows as (
insert into "Contact"(name, gender, city, birthdate)
    values
           ('Name', 1, 'City', '2000-02-03')
           returning id
            )
insert into "Education"(user_id, place, degree, endyear)
    select id , 'some_place', 'some_state', 1990 from rows
```

This way I can add one additional entry, but I need several. If I try to do the second insert query - postgre loses relation "rows"

```
with rows as (
insert into "Contact"(name, gender, city, birthdate)
    values
           ('Name', 1, 'City', '2000-02-03')
           returning id
            )
insert into "Education"(user_id, place, degree, endyear)
    select id , 'some_place', 'some_state', 1990 from rows
insert into "Status"(user_id, status)
    select id , 'val' from rows
```

```
ERROR:  relation "rows" does not exist
LINE 11:     select id , 'val' from rows
                                             ^
SQL state: 42P01
Character: 373
```

is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to put all statements in an [anonymous code block](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-do.html). You could use the `RETURNING` into a variable and from there execute the following inserts, e.g.

```
DO $$
DECLARE returned_id int;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO contact 
    (name, gender, city, birthdate) VALUES 
    ('Name', 1, 'City', '2000-02-03')
  RETURNING id INTO returned_id;
  
  INSERT INTO education 
    (user_id, place, degree, endyear) VALUES 
    (returned_id, 'some_place', 'some_state', '1990-01-01');
    
  INSERT INTO status 
    (user_id, status) VALUES 
    (returned_id, 'val');   
END;
$$;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=419a91d7bc8575e2c70eea656cec10e1)

Comment: Thank you, it`s really convenient! Doesn't this load the system more?

Comment: @JeanPanov I do not think so, at least I never noticed any decrease in performance using anonymous code blocks - specially not with simple insert statements. cheers